# python numpy array, sub-array with satisfied condition problem

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have an array `X = np.array([1,-3,5,0,9,12])`

I wanna make a function a like this.

```
def bigfunction(X)
    if X<0:
        return 99
    if X=>0 and X<=10
        return 100
    if X>10
        return 101
```

Which return also an array. In this case `[100,99,100,100,100,101]`
Obviously, this code will not work.
It is very import that I can't do it in a loop. I am wondering that if there has implemented the code in numpy solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
conds = [X < 0, X <= 10]

choices = [99, 100]

np.select(conds, choices, default=101)
```

This will return:

```
array([100,  99, 100, 100, 100, 101])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Y = np.zeros(X.shape, dtype=int)
Y[X<0] = 99
Y[(X>= 0) & (X<10)] = 100
Y[X>10] = 101
```

Where `Y` will be your returned array.

Comment: You can also use `np.zeros_like(X, dtype=np.int)`